# Latitudes and longitudes from ISO country codes

Tags: r, r-leaflet

I have been looking now for a while and I fail to find a package which returns latitudes and longitudes of ISO country codes.

There are datasets which contain many countries and their respective latitudes / longitudes, but the lists I found do not include "countries" like the Cayman Islands, etc..
My plan would be to get longitudes and latitudes for almost every "country" with an ISO 3 code, here is a list:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3

or the countries which I use specifically:

```
country_url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lukes/ISO-3166-Countries-with-Regional-Codes/master/all/all.csv"

country_all_codes <- readr::read_csv(url(country_url))
```

The latitudes and longitudes should then be used in a `leaflet` map!

Any comment is appreciated!

PS:
Principally it should work with the `ggmap package`, but since I am writing the code for someone else, I don't want to be registered with an Google account..

Comment: Are you looking for lattitude/longitude of the centroid of every country? Countries do not have a singular lattitude/longintude, since they are two-dimensional shapes.

Comment: Does this link help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71921/list-of-central-coordinates-centroid-for-all-countries

Comment: @CaptainHat Yes exactly, I should have specified this in my question.

Comment: @Peter Thanks yes some useful stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can source the list of countries (with spatial information) via `giscoR::gisco_get_counties()`.

It will return countries as polygons, to reduce the data to single points consider `sf::st_centroid()`. Just be aware that there can be some confusion on what constitutes a country - does "France" as a country mean [Metropolitan France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolitan_France) full stop, or are the overseas parts in? These will have an impact on the location of the centroid. Some tweaking may be necessary.

But the dataset does contain Cayman Islands, has a column for ISO code and is compatible with both `ggmap` and `leaflet` packages.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

countries <- giscoR::gisco_get_countries() %>% 
  st_centroid()

leaflet(data = countries) %>% 
  addProviderTiles("Stamen.Watercolor") %>%
  addMarkers(label = ~ ISO3_CODE)
```

Also note that with the choice of basemap is highly personal. I am mostly showing off with the watercolor, Stamen.Toner or CartoDB.Positron might be more sensible choices...

[image: map of carribean with cayman islands highlighted]

Comment: Thanks this is really nice!! My dataset also includes countries like Saint Martin (french part), which I don't find in the giscoR dataset, but Sint Maarten is in there, that's already good! (:   Helped me out a lot thanks!

Comment: Thanks, glad to be of service - and coincidentally the reason Saint Martin (french part) does not figure in the countries dataset is because it is not legally a country, but a part of overseas France. Tricky indeed!

Comment: Yes I should find a way around this.. Thanks a lot!